# Is it possible to upload files without having access to the default temporary directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a very generic file-uploading script in php. The problem however is that the server i'm hosting my website on **doesn't** allow me to configure php.ini and the `upload_tmp_dir`. Things like `ini_set('upload_tmp_dir','your_directory_path')` does not work either due to the fact that the `upload_tmp_dir` will already have been executed by the the time `ini_set` is run.

Is it possible to upload files (any language) that bypasses the temporary-file creation? Since the function `move_uploaded_file($temp_file, $target_file);` prohibits me from doing this with my current solution.

I don't have access to the servers root/tmp (which is the location where the temporary files will be stored on the server). I understand why the hosting company doesn't allow people to change the temp root because there's probably a lot of customers on that same server. So changing the php.ini file would affect all users on the server.

Also, I've seen some solutions on changing the vhost.conf file (which in theory would be able to fix this on a client to client basis, but i've been in contact with the service-provider and they seem very reluctant on helping me change this)

My php-script:

```
$target_directory = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/";
$filename = $_POST['fileLocation'];
$temp_filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$size = $_FILES["file"]["size"];

// Produce a unique filename
$randomNumber = time();
$filetype = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.'));
$target_file = $target_directory . $randomNumber . $filetype;
$local_path = "/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/" . $randomNumber . $filetype;

// Make sure the webserver process owner owns the destination folder
// run exec('whoami'), Mac could be _www
if(!move_uploaded_file($temp_filename, $target_file))
            //

// = = = = Add to database = = = =
// Establish connection to database
$conn = mysql_connect("***", "***", "***") or die(mysql_error());
//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db("***");

// Collect data from form
$companyname = $_POST["companyname"];
$companytext = $_POST["companytext"];

$query = "INSERT INTO posts (companyname, companytext, image) VALUES ('$companyname', '$companytext', '$local_path')";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
        //
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: On topic: What error message are you getting? `$target_directory` doesn't look right to me, unless your website is really deployed directly into the filesystem root (see leading `/`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have no access to the default `upload_tmp_dir` and cannot change it you should switch to a different hoster. Even more so if you have contacted them and they are *reluctant to help you with this*.

There may be technical solutions to your issue but none of them really matter if it should work out of the box in a normal hosting environment.

Comment: yeah... It's actually a client i'm working for, so i really don't have the luxury of making those decisions. I advice against ever using `one` as a provider tho.

Comment: If they are paying you they should listen to your advice, including "this hosting provider does not provide a proper environment to do your work in".